# HOW TO REMOVE A ROW WITH S/N

Tags: r

IPlease someone should help

I get the below whenever i try to run this script

```
row.names(otumat) <- otumat[,1]
```

> Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length
> In addition: Warning message:
> Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

It is a `tibble`.  Thus, we need to extract the column with `[[` or else it will still be a tibble with single column.  Also, `tibble` rownames are discouraged as is mentioned in the `?tbl_df`

> Row names are not added and are strongly discouraged, in favor of storing that info as a column. Read about in rownames.

> df[, j] returns a tibble; it does not automatically extract the column inside. df[, j, drop = FALSE] is the default.

Or the `?rownames`

> While a tibble can have row names (e.g., when converting from a regular data frame), they are removed when subsetting with the [ operator.

We can convert to data.frame and assign

```
otumat <- as.data.frame(otumat)
row.names(otumat) <- otumat[,1]
```